# How to open trim audio panel in IMG.LY

Tags: android, audio, video, trim

I woud like to open audio trim editor in VideoEditor IMG.LY from my action. How can I do this?
Native implementation works but before that I must to open separate display and select audio from audio list. I would like set my audio file and open with file trim audio feature immediatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip the audio selection dialog in VideoEditor IMG.LY and set the audio track, you can use the following code:

```
    settingsList.configure<AudioOverlaySettings> { 
        it.audioOverlay = AudioTrackAsset(...) 
}
```

However, if the user removes the audio track, the audio selection dialog will reappear. To prevent this, you can remove the delete button from the UiConfigAudio.quickOptionList.